# Existence of sequence of functions converging to integrable function in $L^1$ and pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, sequence-of-function

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Show that if $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is integrable, then there exists $f_n$ which are integrable and $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise and in $L^1$.

Attempt: The question says not to use the fact that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ implies there is a subsequence $f_{n_j} \rightarrow f$ pointwise. However, my method relies on this notion. Is there any different way to do this?

Since $f$ is integrable, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a continuous function $g_n \in L^1$ vanishing outside a bounded interval s.t. $\int|g_n-f|<\frac{1}{n}$. Thus, $\int|g_n-f| \rightarrow 0$ and $g_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$. Since $g_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$, there is a subsequence such that $g_{n_j} \rightarrow f$ pointwise. Further, $g_{n_j} \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$.

Edit: I realize my approach is badly flawed, so I will try to use useful comments to do this. Let $f_n=(1-\frac{1}{n})f$. Then $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise since $1-\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 1$. Since $|(1-\frac{1}{n})f|\leq |f|$, by the dominating convergence theorem, $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$.

Comment: The only thing we know is integrable is $f$, so we should sneak up on $f$.  $f_n = (1-\frac{1}{n})f$ is a way to sneak up on $f$.

Comment: I am puzzled by this question. You could even take the constant sequence $f_n = f$. Do you want a sequence $f_n$ with any particular properties, like $f_n$ is a simple function? Also note that if $X$ is only a measure space, there is not a notion of continuous function unless $X$ also has a topology.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz yea, I am definitely using the wrong approach since I am using a theorem from Folland which only applies to Lebesgue measure spaces.

Comment: @EricTowers I have tried to use your comments to make a correct argument. Would this be ok?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz i guess by your comment, that this problem is actually trivial. I do not know if there were any constraints on $f_n$, it does not say.

Comment: @Mauro: You may like trying to prove that if $f$ is integrable and if the measure space $X$ is $\sigma$-finite, there is a sequence of simple functions that converge to $f$ pointwise and in $L^1$. This result is true, not so trivial as asking for an arbitrary sequence converging in $L^1$ and pointwise, and very useful. You should start with $f\ge 0$ and integrable, then treat general integrable functions by decomposing $f = f^+-f^-$.